# When is the inverse image of continuous function a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $f : R^n → R$ be a continuous function. Let $c ∈ Im f$. When is $f
^{−1}(c)$ a manifold?

I know that if $f$ is a smooth function then $f
^{−1}(c)$ is a manifold if $c$ is a regular value. But what can we say about continuous functions?

Also, if $g : R → R^n$ be a continuous function. When is $Im (g)$ a manifold?

Comment: You can say very, very little.

Comment: There are different notions of manifold.  A *topological* manifold only requires *continuous* charts.  For example, the continuous function $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $f(x_1, x_2) = \max \{|x_1|, |x_2|\}$ has preimages such as $f^{-1}(c)$ for $c > 0$ that is a square of side length $2c$, which is a topological manifold (not smooth because of the corners).

Comment: Would you like to add some details about what you've tried so far ? Otherwise we might assume this is some homework problem, no ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really say much - given an arbitrary closed set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, the distance function $f(x) = d(A,x)$ is continuous and $A = f^{-1}(0)$ so any closed subset is the inverse image of a continuous function but most of them are very far from being manifolds.